# 3 variables 'linked' to one outcome (for lack of better words)

Tags: real-analysis, education, regression, regression-analysis

Paper route salary formula (reverse engineer...again for lack of a better word;)

Ok suppose I have these variables:

Pieces of mail : 302
Number of stops: 177
TotalWeight*   : 272

Hours allocated: 1(:)48

Another 4 numbers: 360(pieces),254(stops),258(weight),229(hours)

- totalweight is actually 27.2KG and 25.8KG, I decided (so far) to just keep them all regular numbers because I think I'm interested in the relation between numbers, not their intrinsic value..might be wrong here, same for Hours allocated which I just give the numbers 148 and 229

Ok so I'm trying to figure out given 302,177 and 272 the outcome is 148 in above example. So how much weight (if any) is given to any (or all) of these variables? I have much more data to work with than above example.

Google took me towards 'regression' in excel and I think I'm on the right track there but my knowledge is just lacking :(. Can someone give a noob a nudge in the right direction, I prefer this to be a learning experience vs 'oh that's easy, here's how you do it' ;).

Thanks in advance,

Mr.Mailman

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1094886/estimating-unknown-weights-of-various-parameters-in-an-equation

Comment: I'm getting a deja vu feeling...last time I asked something seemingly easy but too hard for me was when a befriended couple stayed at my place for a holiday....he's a nuclear engineer so he did come up with an answer but had a hard time explaining it...a 'NP-Hard' time (yeah learned some vocabulary too) as it turned out ;). Looks like this question is heading in the same direction as below link/question seems to be what I'm asking too:

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1094886/estimating-unknown-weights-of-various-parameters-in-an-equation

Comment: I posted on a bunch of other sites and in the process came up with another example of what I'm trying to (approximate) accomplish:

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot:

3 numbers might or might NOT influence the outcome of the fourth number. 

I have months of data on all 4 numbers. How do I determine how or if the 3 numbers are weighted. 

Ok a real world example with those 4 numbers: 

Your boss tells you to pick 20 (nr1) apples from 3 (nr2) different trees and their total weight is 4(nr3) kilogram - Your boss tells you that is worth 30 (nr4) minutes of work time.

Comment: The next day you pick 50 apples from 13 different tree with a total weight of 12 kilogram - Your boss tells you this time it's worth 45 minutes of work time (for example). etc etc

Well even if it doesn't help you, writing this has helped me put it into perspective :)